# What is the intention of undocumented option "netserver -D"?

Tags: documentation

The `netserver` binary is often used for network performance profiling in conjunction with `iperf3`. In [many contexts](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22netserver+-D%22) including other Stack Exchange questions, the method for launching `netserver` is shown with a mystery `-D` option.

The `-D` option is not documented in the manpage `netserver(1)`, neither does the option appear to do anything different, nor is the reason for launching with `-D` given anywhere else I can discover.

So my question, if it can be answered - **what is the `-D` option intended to do?** and by extension, **where is the `-D` option documented?**

Here's a sample unitfile containing the `-D`, per [Flavio's Blog](http://flavioleitner.blogspot.com/2015/03/netperf-netserver-systemd-service-unit.html) which is close to what I'm using:

```
[Unit]
Description="Netperf netserver daemon"
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/netserver -D

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to find out is to [look at the source code](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/netperf/blob/859128b58fe5ed04b134d415fbb8f4e3a20135b6/src/netserver.c#L1300): `-D` causes `netserver` to *not* dæmonise, and to skip checking whether it’s an `inetd` child.

`netserver -h` mentions this (partially):

```
Usage: netserver [options]

Options:
[...]
    -D                Do not daemonize
```

So the purpose of the option, in `netserver`, is to prevent it from dæmonising, *i.e.* forking itself to run in the background.

The point of this option in the systemd unit is to make it [easier to handle](https://jdebp.eu/FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html) as a service.

Comment: The latter page appears to have been written several years after this option.  You might want to find a source from which the developer got ideas, rather than the reverse.

Comment: I’m not trying to explain why the option was added to `netserver`, but why it’s used in the systemd unit.

Comment: You clinched it because of `netserver -h` which I totally missed. Thomas's answer is really good also for other reasons. I wish the two answers could be merged!

Answer (score 2):

**`D`** likely stands for **debug**, though no indication of its intent was provided by the [developer](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/netperf/blob/bcb868bde7f0203bbab69609f65d4088ba7398db/AUTHORS#L9) when adding it ([possibly](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/netperf/blob/bcb868bde7f0203bbab69609f65d4088ba7398db/AUTHORS#L13) on behalf of another):

```
commit 88eecaf68174e4e0190e2b866e0bcb59b81b6061                                 
Author: raj <raj@5bbd99f3-5903-0410-b283-f1d88047b228>                          
Date:   Mon Jul 11 21:58:41 2011 +0000                                          
                                                                            
massive re-write of src/netserver.c to clean out old spaghetti allow multiple listen sockets for control and run netserver without daemonizing or spawning children to avoid fork calls which may not sit well with various bypass libraries.  this has probably broken the Windows code and perhaps other platforms as well but it has been tested under linux
```

Use the [source](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/netperf/blob/bcb868bde7f0203bbab69609f65d4088ba7398db/src/netserver.c#L1300) (i.e., read `netserver.c`):

```
case 'D':
  /* perhaps one of these days we'll take an argument */
  want_daemonize = 0;
  not_inetd = 1;
  break;
```

The first variable `want_daemonize` is used in the [same file](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/netperf/blob/bcb868bde7f0203bbab69609f65d4088ba7398db/src/netserver.c#L1561) to control whether the program puts itself into the [background](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/netperf/blob/bcb868bde7f0203bbab69609f65d4088ba7398db/src/netserver.c#L1385):

```
/* we are the top netserver process, so we have to create the
   listen endpoint(s) and decide if we want to daemonize */
setup_listens(local_host_name,listen_port,local_address_family);
if (want_daemonize) {
  daemonize();
}
accept_connections();
```

The other variable, `not_inetd` controls whether it [attempts](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/netperf/blob/bcb868bde7f0203bbab69609f65d4088ba7398db/src/netserver.c#L1447) to open a socket to the `inetd` service.

The developers probably had in mind the longstanding behavior of other programs, e.g., as described in this 2002 section [*29.2.1 Invoking a standalone service*](https://rlworkman.net/howtos/rute/node32.html#SECTION003221000000000000000) (although in effect reversing the sense of the option):

> Try the following (alternative commands in parentheses):
>
> `/usr/sbin/in.ftpd -D`
> `( /usr/sbin/in.wuftpd -s )`
>
> The **`-D`** option instructs the service to start in *Daemon* mode (or standalone mode). This represents the first way of running an Internet service.

Comment: Really great info, Thomas! Although you kinda flubbed (as did I by missing usage info in `netserver -h`) where you say "no indication" because he says it: _and run netserver without daemonizing or spawning children to avoid fork calls_. Merging these two answers would be a useful addition to the `netserver` documentation :-)